# Join two paths with a border

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, borders

This is probably far easier than I'm making it out to be.. I have this path that I duplicated and reflected but since both paths have a border I'm not sure how to join them so that the path is just one continuous path (without a line down the middle separating them...)

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Just use the shape builder tool. (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>)

Select both Shapes

[image]

Using the shape builder tool, drag and connect them.

[image]

They should now be merged into one shape

[image]

---

You can also use the Pathfinder [*Window → Pathfinder* or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd>]

*(Unite option)*

Again, select both shapes, and hit the *Unite* Button

[image]