# Connecting two separately filled shapes

Tags: adobe-illustrator

In Illustrator CC, in order to connect two separately filled shapes, first select the shapes, and then drag across from one to the other with *which* tool?

Comment: This will be helpful for you https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/104305/63979

Comment: I changed your question a bit to make it clearer, I hope I didn't mess it up. Feel free to change it if I did.

Answer (score 1):

Move them with the black arrow tool which is the main selection tool.

Arrange the two shapes in the way you want them to be attached, select both and choose Pathfinder>Unite.

They will now be one shape sharing one fill.